# Convert String to MessageBoxIcon

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is it possible to set MessageBoxIcon by drawing strings from an array?

Requirement: 
Need to display a message box where I have all required values in string format.

```
Dim MessageTitle as String = "Procedure is starting in 10 seconds"
Dim MessageBody as String = "Some description here"
Dim MessageIcon as String = "MessageBoxIcon.Information"
Dim MessageButtons as String = "MessageBoxButtons.OK"

MessageBox.Show(MessageBody, MessageTitle, Ctype(MessageButtons, MessageBoxButtons), Ctype(MessageIcon, MessageBoxIcon))
```

I am stuck with invalid cast exception because MessageBoxIcon is an integer and hence String type cannot be converted to MessageBoxIcon. Is there some way in which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

[MessageBoxButtons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons(v=vs.110).aspx) and [MessageBoxIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon(v=vs.110).aspx) are enumeration type. You can use [Enum.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) method to convert a string value to enumeration value. I change your string so it only contains the value.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim MessageTitle As String = "Procedure is starting in 10 seconds"
    Dim MessageBody As String = "Some description here"
    Dim MessageIcon As String = "Information"
    Dim MessageButtons As String = "OKCancel"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim msgButton As MessageBoxButtons = [Enum].Parse(GetType(MessageBoxButtons), MessageButtons)
        Dim msgIcon As MessageBoxIcon = [Enum].Parse(GetType(MessageBoxIcon), MessageIcon)

        MessageBox.Show(MessageBody, MessageTitle, msgButton, msgIcon)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        AddIcons()
        AddButtons()
        ShowIConz(1, 1)

    End Sub
    Public Sub AddIcons()

        MIcon.Add(MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)      '0
        MIcon.Add(MessageBoxIcon.Error)         '1
        MIcon.Add(MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)   '2
        MIcon.Add(MessageBoxIcon.Hand)          '3
        MIcon.Add(MessageBoxIcon.Information)   '4
        MIcon.Add(MessageBoxIcon.None)          '5
        MIcon.Add(MessageBoxIcon.Question)      '6
        MIcon.Add(MessageBoxIcon.Stop)          '7
        MIcon.Add(MessageBoxIcon.Warning)       '8

    End Sub
    Public Sub AddButtons()

        MButton.Add(MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore) '0
        MButton.Add(MessageBoxButtons.OK)               '1
        MButton.Add(MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)         '2
        MButton.Add(MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel)      '3
        MButton.Add(MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)            '4
        MButton.Add(MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)      '5

    End Sub
    Public Sub ShowIConz(iconnumber As Double, buttonnumber As Double)

        Dim MessageTitle As String = "Procedure is starting in 10 seconds"
        Dim MessageBody As String = "Some description here"
        UseIcon = MIcon(iconnumber)
        UseButton = MButton(buttonnumber)

        MessageBox.Show(MessageBody, MessageTitle, UseButton, UseIcon)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET to achieve this

This will creates a dictionary of MessageBox Buttons,here I used `"OK"` instead of `MessageBoxButtons.OK` its more convenient or your alter it

```
Dim MsgBox_Buttons As New Dictionary(Of String, MessageBoxButtons)
With MsgBox_Buttons
    .Add("OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    .Add("OKCancel", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
    .Add("AbortRetryIgnore", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore)
    .Add("RetryCancel", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel)
    .Add("YesNo", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    .Add("YesNoCancel", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
End With
```

This will creates a dictionary of MessageBox Buttons,here I used `Information"` instead of `MessageBoxIcon.Information` its more convenient or your alter it

```
Dim MsgBox_Icons As New Dictionary(Of String, MessageBoxIcon)
With MsgBox_Icons
    .Add("Asterisk", MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    .Add("Error", MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    .Add("Exclamation", MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    .Add("Hand", MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
    .Add("Information", MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    .Add("None", MessageBoxIcon.None)
    .Add("Question", MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    .Add("Stop", MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
    .Add("Warning", MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
End With

Dim MessageTitle As String = "Procedure is starting in 10 seconds"
Dim MessageBody As String = "Some description here"
Dim MessageIcon As String = "Information" 'note this change (You can alter it but the change should be don in the dictionary also)
Dim MessageButtons As String = "OK" 'note this change(You can alter it but the change should be don in the dictionary also)

MessageBox.Show(MessageBody, MessageTitle, MsgBox_Buttons.Item(MessageButtons), MsgBox_Icons.Item(MessageIcon))
```

---

Complete Code is [here](https://gist.github.com/wingedpather/5e58429d1198d87ce595)

*More About* `Dictionary()` *is* [*here*](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet)